# Who can use Delta express check-in?

Tags: air-travel, check-in, united-airlines, delta-air-lines, slc

I [read](https://slcairport.com/airport-services/skycap/) on the SLC official website that Delta and United Airlines have an express check-in at Salt Lake City Airport (SLC):

> [Delta Air Lines](https://maps.slcairport.com/?s=eyJvbmxpbmUvaGVhZGVyT25saW5lIjp7ImlkIjoib25saW5lL2hlYWRlck9ubGluZSIsInNlYXJjaCI6IiIsImlzU2VhcmNoQ29uZmlybWVkIjpmYWxzZX0sIm9ubGluZS9wb2lWaWV3Ijp7ImlkIjoib25saW5lL3BvaVZpZXciLCJwb2lJZCI6IjMxMDEifSwib25saW5lL2dldERpcmVjdGlvbnNGcm9tVG8iOnsiaWQiOiJvbmxpbmUvZ2V0RGlyZWN0aW9uc0Zyb21UbyJ9LCJ2ZW51ZURhdGFMb2FkZXIiOnsiaWQiOiJ2ZW51ZURhdGFMb2FkZXIifSwibWFwUmVuZGVyZXIiOnsiaWQiOiJtYXBSZW5kZXJlciIsInZwIjp7ImxhdCI6NDAuNzgzNDE5LCJsbmciOi0xMTEuOTg0NzExLCJ6b29tIjoxOS45MTY2Mzk3NTQ0MDIxNDQsImJlYXJpbmciOjAsInBpdGNoIjowfSwib3JkIjoyfX0%3D) and [United Airlines](https://maps.slcairport.com/?s=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%3D) also offer express check-in in the Gateway Center, which is connected to the second level of the parking garage. The Gateway Center is also accessible by two bridges from the second level of the terminal.

Who can use it?

Comment: thats a good question! i THINK they just mean, let's call it, "distant check in desk", ie, exactly like curbside check in.  It's just "yet another" check in spot - anyone at all can use - rather than waiting in the "horrible main checkin lines".  IDK though.  Can't ever remember seeing it there.

Comment: I suspect it is intended for those who don't check in luggage. I don't think it's connected to the airport luggage moving system. But haven't been at SLC in years, so can't say for sure.